# Elasticsearch refreshing indices, but documents still don't show up in search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating some documents on an index, using bulk.
I can access them using get or mget.
When I do a search, those documents did't show up.
So, I decided to refresh the indices.
However, in some cases, it still happens that even after refreshing, the search can't find those documents, even though the exist.

I've read the official documentation, and it seems that bulk allows for a refresh parameter, but I'm not sure if it's really what I want, or whether there's something better.

Also, this problem appears quite randomly...

Comment: "...even after refreshing, the search can't find..." this is highly unlikely... Can you share your index settings, mappings and the query you're running?

Comment: Elasticsearch by default gives only top 10 documents in the search result, if your document is not coming in the top 10 documents try increasing the `size` param value and see if it comes with the bigger size value, in Elasticsearch response under `hits` Elasticsearch returns the `total` documents matching the search result.

Comment: @Val is there a waiting period until the refresh task is completed?

Comment: By default it's 1s